# How to get the arrow keys to print they are located on the key pad

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a laptop Windows 7, and I am trying to use the arrow keys found on #4 and #6. I can't figure out how to get them to work.

Comment: Including laptop's brand make and model would help to answer your question. In general, there should be a key at the bottom of the keyboard and more to the left corner - ie Fn that usually enables

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. Do you want them to work, as in typing numbers or going left/right etc, or do you want them to print something? Anyway, in most laptops (this would be easier if you had included your laptop model), there is a special function key that enables the "num pad".

Either you have a dedicated numpad (which very few laptops do). In that case, you can toggle the behavior of the keys bu hitting the "NumLock" button ([source](http://vicksr18.blogspot.fr/2011/11/trick-to-enabled-num-lock-automatically.html)):

[image]

If your laptop does not have a dedicated numpad, there will be a combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd> and some other button to enable it. For example ([source](http://lytebyte.blogspot.fr/2012_12_01_archive.html)):

[image]

If you update your question with your specific laptop model, and an explanation of what you mean by "work" I should be able to give you a more detailed answer.